# Intercept call to refresh token GRPC

Tags: android, kotlin, interceptor, grpc

I am using GRPC with proto in my project and I have KEY and AUTHORITY tokens to access the server API.
So, I need to update KEY using my AUTHORITY.
I am building Channel like this:

```
OkHttpChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port)
        .usePlaintext()
        .intercept(auth, logger)
        .build()
```

My interceptor looks like:

```
class AuthClientInterceptor(
    private val prefs: Preferences,
    private val keyApi: KeyApi) : ClientInterceptor {

    companion object {
        private const val ACCESS_TOKEN = "authorization"
    }

    override fun <ReqT : Any?, RespT : Any?> interceptCall(method: MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT>?,
                                                       callOptions: CallOptions?,
                                                       next: Channel): ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> {

        val call = next.newCall(method, callOptions)

        val callForwarding = object : ClientInterceptors.CheckedForwardingClientCall<ReqT, RespT>(call) {
            override fun checkedStart(responseListener: Listener<RespT>?, headers: Metadata) {

            synchronized(this@AuthClientInterceptor) {
                val keyCreated = prefs.getAccessKeyCreated()
                val keyExpires = prefs.getAccessKeyExpires()
                val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                if (currentTime < keyCreated || currentTime > keyExpires) {
                    keyApi.issueNewKey(prefs.getAuthority())
                        .map { it.data }
                        .doOnSuccess { prefs.setAccessKey(it.token) }
                        .doOnSuccess { prefs.setAccessKeyCreated(it.createdDate) }
                        .doOnSuccess { prefs.setAccessKeyExpires(it.expiresDate) }
                        .blockingGet()
                }
            }

            val keyData = Metadata.Key.of(ACCESS_TOKEN, Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER)
                if (headers[keyData] == null) {
                    headers.put(keyData, "Bearer ${prefs.getAccessKey()}")
                }
                call.start(responseListener, headers)
            }
        }
        return callForwarding
    }
}
```

As you can see, I just check current time and compare it with token created and expiry dates.

So, I don't like that way. I want implement this:

1) Send request to server;

2) Check response. If it means, that my KEY expired, refresh key synchronously and repeat the request (like authenticator).

But I didn't find the solution or any helpful information about implementing this with gRPC. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Did you find anything on this?

Comment: @VarunRaj nope, we still checking time before request =/

Comment: Oh man, that's a bummer.

Comment: yes, I didn't find anything that could help me implement that logic

Comment: Hey, I have asked this question on the `grpc-java` GitHub account here is the link `https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/6638`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full client interceptor class you can use.

```
class Interceptor() : ClientInterceptor {

    override fun <ReqT : Any?, RespT : Any?> interceptCall(method: MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT>?, callOptions: CallOptions?, next: Channel?): ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> {

        return object : ClientCall<ReqT, RespT>() {

            var listener: Listener<RespT>? = null
            var metadata: Metadata? = null
            var message: ReqT? = null
            var request = 0
            var call: ClientCall<ReqT, RespT>? = null

            override fun start(responseListener: Listener<RespT>?, headers: Metadata?) {
                this.listener = responseListener
                this.metadata = headers
            }

            override fun sendMessage(message: ReqT) {
                assert(this.message == null)
                this.message = message
            }

            override fun request(numMessages: Int) {
                request += numMessages
                assert(this.message == null)
            }

            override fun isReady(): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun halfClose() {

                startCall(object : ForwardingClientCallListener<RespT>() {

                    var delegate: Listener<RespT>? = null

                    override fun onReady() {
                        delegate = listener
                        super.onReady()
                    }

                    override fun delegate(): Listener<RespT> {
                        if (delegate == null) {
                            throw IllegalStateException()
                        }
                        return delegate!!
                    }

                    override fun onClose(status: Status?, trailers: Metadata?) {
                        if (delegate == null) {
                            super.onClose(status, trailers)
                            return
                        }
                        if (!needToRetry(status, trailers)) {
                            delegate = listener
                            super.onClose(status, trailers)
                            return
                        }
                        startCall(listener) // Only retry once
                    }

                    private fun needToRetry(status: Status?, trailers: Metadata?): Boolean {
                        if (status?.code?.toStatus() == UNAUTHENTICATED) {
                            Log.e("code", status?.code.toString())
                            return true
                        }
                        return false
                    }
                })
            }

            private fun startCall(listener: Listener<RespT>?) {
                call = next?.newCall(method, callOptions)
                val headers = Metadata()
                headers.merge(metadata)
                call?.start(listener, headers)
                assert(this.message != null)
                call?.request(request)
                call?.sendMessage(message)
                call?.halfClose()
            }

            override fun cancel(message: String?, cause: Throwable?) {
                if (call != null) {
                    call?.cancel(message, cause)
                }
                listener?.onClose(Status.CANCELLED.withDescription(message).withCause(cause), Metadata())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It buffers the message and retries, you can add your logic in `needToRetry(status, trailers)`

For more information, you can visit this GitHub [link.](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/5856#issuecomment-511077021)

Comment: it doesn't work, because previous call will be closed anyway with error. 
We can't just hold it, refresh our token, and then repeat the same call with new token and pass valid response using grpc interceptors.

Answer (score 0):

This works. I'm using Koin for Dependency Injection, and Datastore.

```
class Interceptor(private val repo: RefreshRepo, private val store: DataStore<AuthResponse>) : ClientInterceptor {
    override fun <ReqT : Any?, RespT : Any?> interceptCall(method: MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT>?, callOptions: CallOptions?, next: Channel?): ForwardingClientCall.SimpleForwardingClientCall<ReqT, RespT> {
        val callOptionsWithDeadline = callOptions?.withDeadlineAfter(4, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        return object : ForwardingClientCall.SimpleForwardingClientCall<ReqT, RespT>(next?.newCall(method, callOptionsWithDeadline)) {
            var call: ClientCall<ReqT, RespT>? = null
            var listener: Listener<RespT>? = null
            var delegate: Listener<RespT>? = null
            var metadata: Metadata? = null
            var message: ReqT? = null
            var request = 0

            override fun sendMessage(message: ReqT) {
                super.sendMessage(message)
                this.message = message
            }

            override fun request(numMessages: Int) {
                super.request(numMessages)
                request += numMessages
            }

            override fun cancel(message: String?, cause: Throwable?) {
                super.cancel(message, cause)
                if (call != null) call?.cancel(message, cause)
                listener?.onClose(Status.CANCELLED.withDescription(message).withCause(cause), Metadata())
            }

            override fun start(responseListener: Listener<RespT>?, headers: Metadata?) {
                listener = responseListener
                metadata = headers

                val accessToken = runBlocking {
                    store.data.first().accessToken // get the accessToken from DataStore
                }

                metadata?.put(key, accessToken)

                super.start(object : ForwardingClientCallListener.SimpleForwardingClientCallListener<RespT>(responseListener) {

                    override fun onMessage(message: RespT) {
                        responseListener?.onMessage(message)
                    }

                    override fun delegate(): Listener<RespT> {
                        delegate = responseListener
                        return delegate!!
                    }

                    override fun onClose(status: Status?, trailers: Metadata?) {
                        if (delegate == null || status?.code?.toStatus() != Status.UNAUTHENTICATED) {
                            super.onClose(status, trailers)
                        } else {
                            delegate = null
                            try {
                                val res = runBlocking {
                                    // refresh and store the accessToken to DataStore
                                    val r = repo.refresh()
                                    val auth = store.data.first().toBuilder()
                                        .setAccessToken(r.accessToken)
                                        .setRefreshToken(r.refreshToken)
                                        .build()
                                    store.updateData { auth }

                                    r
                                }

                                call = next?.newCall(method, callOptionsWithDeadline)
                                val md = Metadata()
                                md.put(key, res.accessToken)
                                md.merge(metadata)
                                call?.start(listener, md)
                                call?.request(request)
                                call?.sendMessage(message)
                                call?.halfClose()
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                super.onClose(status, trailers)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, headers)
            }
        }
    }

    private val key: Metadata.Key<String>
        get() = Metadata.Key.of("authorization", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to do that, I think you will have to handle it at the application level exactly as you described. This is because gRPC does not know about your application level tokens.

1. Make the RPC
2. Notice that the RPC failed due to an expired token
3. Call your code that refreshes the token
4. Repeat

What is the authenticator that you are referring to?

Comment: In Step 2, is thee a standard error/exception at gRPC level ? (when server notices that token has expired)
Or is it at application level ?